# I'm having trouble with changing a picturebox from a class C#

Tags: c#, class, picturebox

I am trying to make a quiz and the player can chose an avatar. However i cant seem to get it to work
I am new to coding so apologies if this is terrible code.

```
        Player player = new Player();
        if (player.Avatar != null)
        {
            picBx_avatar.Image = Image.FromFile(player.Avatar);
        }
        else
        {    picBx_avatar.Image = Image.FromFile(@"");
        }
```

This is the code on the form 1 that shows the avatar. If the value is null it will set the avatar to the default. If avatar has a value that will be the file location string

```
        Player player = new Player();

        if (rad_avatar1.Checked == true)
        {
            player.Avatar = avatar1_file;
        }
```

This is the code in the avatar picker dialog form to change the file location in the class

```
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
```

and this is the sting in the Player class.

However no matter what avatar is picked it will always be the default avatar.

edit i fixed this by change the class operator to

```
public static string Avatar;
```

Comment: have you tried to debug your app?

Comment: yeah. it says "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for the document"

Comment: there are many solutions for this issue on SO

Comment: I havent been able to find any could you link some?

Comment: Your code shows 3 (three!) times `Player player = new Player();
` why are you always creating a new instance and what do you do with it?? The one created in the button click is not kept but lost after the event is finished! You need to have a plan for __keeping__ the reference to the new Player!

Comment: @TaW they are in different forms. adding `static` to the class operator fixed it and allows me to write to the sting in the class from another form

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
public string Avatar { get; set; }
```

to

```
public static string Avatar;
```